# MongoDb: Establishing a Many-To-Many relation that may exceed millions of documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many, relation

I am building a social media app in which each user can follow an indefinite number of other users.
According to this [website](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/), there are two ways of building this relation in the code. Either by Two Way Embedding or One Way Embedding.

One Way Embedding is to be used if the relation is asymmetric. I.e: Model A can have a huge number of Model B whereas Model B has a very limited number of Model A.

Two Way Embedding is to be used if the relation is somewhat symmetric. I.e: Model A has almost as many Model B as Model B has model A.
**This is in order not to exceed the size limit of a document.**
Check the linked [website](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/) for more details.

The problem with my project is the relation is between the model and itself.
In other words, the model is User and it can follow other Users.

So, a user will follow a big number of other users, the size of his document might exceed the size limit.
So the question is:
**Should I implement the Many-To-Many relation without using the embedding approach?**

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate collection for links between users, reference both user ids from that collection.